# SEVERE Error in deploying WAR in Tomcat .ContainerBase addChildInternal error

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web.xml, classnotfoundexception

I am not able to deploy my application war file in Tomcat Server version 7.0.54. Here is the error log.

[image: ERR LOG 1]

[image: ERR LOG2]

**WEB.XML**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>branding</param-name>
    <param-value>default</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>brandingTitle</param-name>
    <param-value>Webchat: Fastpath</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Uncomment to specify your own logging
<context-param>
    <param-name>logging</param-name>
    <param-value>file://c:/log_file.log</param-value>
</context-param>
-->

<!-- Uncomment to specify your own location for the settings file
<context-param>
    <param-name>settings</param-name>
    <param-value>file://c:/my_settings.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
-->

<filter>
    <filter-name>SetupFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jivesoftware.webchat.SetupFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>errorPage</param-name>
        <param-value>fatal.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
 <filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncoder</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jivesoftware.webchat.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SetupFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncoder</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<!-- Servlets -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FastpathServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jivesoftware.webchat.FastpathServlet</servlet-class>
    <!-- Uncomment to have console debugger enabled
    <init-param>
       <param-name>smackDebugger</param-name>
       <param-value>org.jivesoftware.smackx.debugger.ConsoleDebugger</param-value>
    </init-param>
    -->
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jivesoftware.webchat.servlets.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DynamicImageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jivesoftware.webchat.servlets.DynamicImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SoundServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jivesoftware.webchat.sounds.SoundServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>


<!-- Adding Direct Web Remoting Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
    <display-name>DWR Servlet</display-name>
    <description>Direct Web Remoter Servlet</description>
    <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>crossDomainSessionSecurity</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!--
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
        <description>Do we startup in debug/test mode?</description>
    </init-param>
    -->
    <load-on-startup>-1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<!-- Servlet mappings -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FastpathServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/live/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/getimage</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DynamicImageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dynoimages/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SoundServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sounds/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<!-- Session config -->
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>jnlp</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-java-jnlp-file</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<!-- Welcome file list -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Please help me get rid of this error!

Thanks

I am using JDK version 1.7. I have seen various solutions, but none have worked so far. It's frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the Issue . It seems I had duplicate smack Jars which i had overlooked .
Silly on my part .:/